Link between semi-algebraic dimension and vector space dimension
I am new to semi-algebraic geometry and I have encountered a very pleasant proposition to define the semi-algebraic dimension of a semi-algebraic subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This definition is based on the fact that any semi-algebraic subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be decomposed as
$$
A=\cup_{k=1}^{n}V_k,
$$
where the $V_k$ are disjoint semi-algebraic subsets homeomorphic to $(0,1)^{e_k}$.
Then the semi-algebraic dimension of the semi-algebraic set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by
$$
\dim(A)=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\{e_k\}.
$$
My question is the following: in the case where $A$ is also a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ do we have a link with the dimension of $A$ as a vector subspace and its semi-algebraic dimension?
Any hint or advice is welcome please.
Thank you a lot!

Of course! If $A$ is both a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and semi-algebraic, then it is linearly and semi-algebraically isomorphic (via the same map, in fact!) to $\Bbb R^d$ with $d$ equal to the vector space dimension, and $\Bbb R^d$ is semi-algebraically isomorphic to $(0,1)^d$, so the vector space and semi-algebraic dimension are the same.

Thank you a lot for the answer !
